# I want to really hightlight all word that i find in editor use QScintilla

Tags: scintilla, qscintilla

This is the effect which i want :

[image]

this is  actual effect.

[image]

```
//follow is code i code：
SendScintilla(QsciScintillaBase::SCI_INDICSETSTYLE,0, INDIC_ROUNDBOX);
SendScintilla(QsciScintillaBase::SCI_INDICSETFORE,0, QColor(Qt::yellow));
```

Comment: Scintilla Docs: [Multiple Selection](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#MultipleSelectionAndVirtualSpace).

Comment: QScintilla Docs: [SendScintilla](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/QScintilla2/classQsciScintillaBase.html#pub-methods).

Comment: not use Multiple Selection.  use SCI_INDICSETSTYLE and SCI_INDICSETFORE and SCI_INDICATORFILLRANGE

Comment: i dont not why the issue remove other editor. i am sorry

Comment: @ekhumoro . Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer.

```cpp
SendScintilla(QsciScintillaBase::SCI_INDICSETSTYLE, 0, INDIC_BOX);

QString docText = text();

int end = docText.lastIndexOf(findText);
int cur = -1; 

if(end != -1) {
    while(cur != end) {
        cur = docText.indexOf(findText,cur+1);
        SendScintilla(QsciScintillaBase::SCI_INDICATORFILLRANGE, cur,
                      findText.length());
    }
}
```

Comment: You can find more information on QScintilla on this source: https://qscintilla.com/